# Edit an Item in a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am creating a to-do app using react js and semantic-ui-library. [image]

Although Add and delete functions are working perfectly, I am stuck at moving on with edit function. Following are code snippets.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
        item :'',

        listItems:[

        ],

    }

    this.handleChangeItem = this.handleChangeItem.bind(this);

  }

updateItem=(key,item)=>{
    const newlistItems = [...this.state.listItems]
    newlistItems.map(list=>{
      if(list.key===key){
        list.item = item;
      }
    }
      )

      this.setState({
        listItems:newlistItems
      })
  }
```

**ListView.js**

```
 <List.Content>

                     { 
                     this.props.listItems.map((item, index) => <List.Header key={index}   > 
                        <span>
                            <input 
                            size="50%"
                             id={index}
                             value={item} 
                             onChange={(event)=>{this.props.updateItem(event.target.value,index)}}
                             />
 </List.Content>
```

I am implementing the edit function in parent component and calling it for `onChange` method in input field of the List View Component. I am unable to edit the value of the input field in the view component.

Can anybody help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `updateItem` function. You can use `setState` with a callback to access the previous state of your state.

Try the following:

```
updateItem = (key, item) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
       ...prevState,
       listItems: prevState.listItems.map(list => {
          if(list.key === key){
             list.item = item;
          }

          return list;
       })
    })
}
```

And maybe on your `onChange` event you want to pass `item` instead of `index`:

```
onChange={ event => { this.props.updateItem(event.target.value, item) } }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I just want to move the cursor in the input field. But I can't do that.Can you help me solving this out?